# How to set active menu option with Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a two column layout.  The left column has a stacked menu, and when the user selects an option the content displays in the right.  What's the best way to set the `active` class on the selected menu link?

I have come up with a solution below, but it seems kind of verbose.  Each menu item has a class assignment which is conditional upon `data.activeTab`.  A click event handler updates the value of `data.activeTab`.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                    <li role="presentation" :class="{active : activeTab == 'option1'}">
                        <a :href="'/#/sales/' + uuid + '/option1'" @click="updateMenu">Option 1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li role="presentation" :class="{active : activeTab == 'option2'}">
                        <a :href="'/#/sales/' + uuid + '/option2'" @click="updateMenu">Option 2</a>
                    </li>
                </ul> 
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <router-view></router-view>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data : function () {
            return {
                activeTab : 'option1'
            }
        },
        props : [
            'uuid'
        ],
        methods : {
            updateMenu : function (event) {
                var str = event.target.toString();
                this.activeTab = str.substr(str.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [router-link](https://router.vuejs.org/en/api/router-link.html) instead of your manual anchor tags and set the `linkActiveClass` in your [router construction options](https://router.vuejs.org/en/api/options.html).

I can't see your routes object, so this is a best guess based on what you have above. Refer to the router link documentation I linked above to determine the best way to set up your `to` attributes.

```
<router-link tag="li" :to="{ path: 'sales', params: { uuid : uuid, option: "option1" }}">
    <a>Option 1</a>
</router-link>
<router-link tag="li" :to="{ path: 'sales', params: { uuid : uuid, option: "option2" }}>
    <a>Option 2</a>
</router-link>
```

Then, wherever you initialized your router,

```
new VueRouter({
    routes,
    linkActiveClass: "active"
});
```

Comment: You solution does work when I just click the link. But it doesn't work for refresh in submenu. I use [admin-lite template](https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/index.html#) for the left sidebar. Would you give me the solution for that?

Comment: Try this
https://forum.vuejs.org/t/how-to-make-a-component-with-menu-item-changing-css-to-active-when-clicked/3235/2